# East US does not show for Add Web App region, shows up for new Database

Tags: azure

I'm trying to add a web app, and when I get to site settings I only see West US, West Europe and North Europe.  I select West US and then for New MySQL Database I see West US, East US, West Europe and North Europe.  If I choose East US, I get a warning that my db and web site are in different regions.

The Azure status page says Web sites for East US is up and running, no downtime for the past week.  What's going on here?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure Websites are currently in proview mode, and therefore availability in datacenters will be based on the capacity available in the preview environments.

Once Windows Azure Websites are fully released they will be available in all datacenters. There have not been any anouncements on this yet, but there may well be some more details ancounced at the Build conferance this week.

Regards,

Alan

Comment: Does it matter where my data center is located?  I live on the west coast... will I be able to switch my data center to a different region at a later date?